# Inner loop runs only once

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I dont know where is the problem, but inner loop runs only once, why?

code: python 2.7

```
for i in range(1,11,5):
   print i
   print '#'
   for j in range(i,6):
       print j
   print '---------------'
```

output:

```
1
#
1
2
3
4
5
---------------
6
#
---------------
```

Require output::

```
1
#
1
2
3
4
5
---------------
6
#
6
7
8
9
10
---------------
```

Comment: With that indentation, it will not be an inner loop :(

Comment: @thefourtheye It's may not be a matter of indentation, just the expected output is wrong

Comment: @thefourtheye no, I mean with even the correct indentation, that code snippet still doesn't get the OP's expected output. That's why I guess the indentation error is just a typo when posting on SO.

Comment: @thefourtheye I was saying the `IndentationError` fix is not what the OP asks for ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces your required output:

```
for i in range(1,11,5):
    print i
    print '#'
    for j in range (i, i+5):
        print j
    print '-------------------'
```

Unless you make both bounds for `j` dependant on `i`, the inner loop will stop to be run when `i` is greater or equal to the fixed upper bound of the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> range(1,11,5)
[1, 6]
```

`range(1,11,5)` only cycles through 1 and 6. This is probably what you don't want... When you run the second for loop, `i` is 6, so `for j in range(i,6)` is `for j in range(6,6)`, so it is only running once.

Comment: His 'required output' suggests that is indeed what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,11,5):
    print i
    print '#'
    for j in range(1,6): # based on your 'required output', the inner loop should run from 1 to 6.
        print j
    print '---------------'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop is `for j in range(i,6):` instead of `for j in range(1,6):`.